# Passing array of a composite type to stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I'm probably doing something wrong with forming the literal. Suppose I have a simple stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_something(input_array composite_type[])
  RETURNS SETOF text AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    temp_var composite_type;
BEGIN

    FOR temp_var IN SELECT unnest(input_array) LOOP
        return next temp_var.message;
    END LOOP;

END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The `composite_type` is defined as:

```
CREATE TYPE composite_type AS
   (message text,
    amount numeric(16,2));
```

Performing a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM do_something('{"(test,11)","(test2,22)"}')
```

Produces this result set:

```
(test,11.00)
(test2,22.00)
```

Instead of:

```
test
test2
```

Is it something wrong with my literal or should I access the `message` field in a different way? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you specify your input appears fine, as the same behaviour is observed with row- and array-constructor syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM do_something( ARRAY[ ROW('test',11), ROW('test2',22) ]::composite_type[] );
```

And:

```
SELECT ARRAY[ ROW('test',11), ROW('test2',22) ]::composite_type[];
```

produces:

```
 '{"(test,11.00)","(test2,22.00)"}'
```

If you add a:

```
 RAISE NOTICE '!%!',temp_var;
```

inside the loop the output is:

```
NOTICE:  !("(test,11.00)",)!
NOTICE:  !("(test2,22.00)",)!
```

showing that you're actually getting a tuple with "message" as the tuple text you expected and a null "amount".

So. Why?

It's a bit of a subtle one. You're using:

```
SELECT unnest(input_array)
```

which seems to do what you want, right:

```
regress=>     SELECT unnest( ARRAY[ ROW('test',11), ROW('test2',22) ]::composite_type[] );
    unnest     
---------------
 (test,11.00)
 (test2,22.00)
(2 rows)
```

...  but actually, it's returning a *single column* of type `composite_type`. PL/PgSQL composite type assignment expects *one column per type column* instead. So the single col is being shoved into 'message' and there is no second col.

Instead, write:

```
SELECT * FROM unnest(input_array)
```

to unpack the composite for assignment. Then it works as expected:

```
regress=> SELECT * FROM do_something( ARRAY[ ROW('test',11), ROW('test2',22) ]::composite_type[] );
 do_something 
--------------
 test
 test2
(2 rows)
```

If the first field of `composite_type` were of a non-text type, you'd get an error that was rather more informative about this.

Comment: Excellent explanation. That's a rather unfortunate design in plpgsql. Bordering a bug. (I was just running the same set of tests. You beat me to it. :) )

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yeah, tend to agree that it's borderline bug.

Comment: @CraigRinger: It is not bug, it is feature :( - it is consequence of two facts: Postgres supports nested composite types - and anybody should be careful on which level of nesting is; and plpgsql is type submissive and use late text based casting - so anything is transformed to text and then to target type - but you lost a metadata about type.

Answer (score 1):

Craig explained well a reason for this behave - Assignment variable=value inside FOR statement expects zero nesting. So you should to do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_something(input_array composite_type[])
RETURNS SETOF text AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    temp_var record;
BEGIN
     -- unnesting
    FOR temp_var IN SELECT (unnest(input_array)).*
    LOOP
        RETURN NEXT temp_var.message;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

or -- preferable - newer use SetReturnedFunction inside "column list"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_something(input_array composite_type[])
RETURNS SETOF text AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    temp_var record;
BEGIN
     -- SELECT FROM
    FOR temp_var IN SELECT * FROM unnest(input_array) 
    LOOP
        RETURN NEXT temp_var.message;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```