# Assign complex type with UUID field from a function call

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, rows, plpgsql, uuid

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3, working with `plpgsql` functions:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE uuid_inside (
    id  uuid PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE FUNCTION uuid_test_func(id uuid)
  RETURNS uuid_inside AS
$$
DECLARE
    res_uuid_inside uuid_inside;
BEGIN
    IF (id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001'::uuid) THEN
        SELECT uuid_test_func('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid)
            INTO res_uuid_inside;
        RETURN res_uuid_inside;
    END IF;

    res_uuid_inside.id := id;

    RETURN res_uuid_inside;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT uuid_test_func('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001'::uuid);
```

Message:

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for uuid: "(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)"
>   SQL-state: 22P02

But this works fine:

```
SELECT uuid_test_func('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002'::uuid);
```

The problem is not with recursive function calling - the original code is refering to some other function inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simple function

The recursion in your function seems pointless. This simple sql function does the job (without nesting and without the composite type wrapper):

```
CREATE FUNCTION uuid_test_func(id uuid)
  RETURNS uuid AS
$func$
SELECT CASE WHEN $1 = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001'::uuid
                 THEN '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid
            ELSE $1
       END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But that's probably just due to simplification for the demo.

#### Address problem in original

As for the **error message**. You are running into a confusing "feature" of PL/pgSQL:
Composite type assignment expects **one column per type column**. Assigning composite types *as a whole* is not an option.

This has nothing to do with the `UUID` type per se.

This modified version would work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uuid_test_func(id uuid)
  RETURNS uuid_inside AS
$func$
DECLARE
    res_uuid_inside uuid_inside;
BEGIN
   IF (id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001'::uuid) THEN
       SELECT * FROM uuid_test_func('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid)
       INTO   res_uuid_inside.id;
  --   INTO   res_uuid_inside;    -- would work, too - 1st col is assigned
       RETURN res_uuid_inside;
   END IF;

   res_uuid_inside.id := id;

   RETURN res_uuid_inside;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Closely related question:
[Passing array of a composite type to stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914227/passing-array-of-a-composite-type-to-stored-procedure/21915226#21915226)

#### Simpler function

That said, I'd suggest this simplified form (keeping the recursion and the composite result):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uuid_test_func(id uuid)
  RETURNS uuid_inside AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF (id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001'::uuid) THEN
      RETURN (SELECT f FROM uuid_test_func('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid) f);
   ELSE
      RETURN row(id)::uuid_inside;
   END IF;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```