# Use of custom return types in a FOR loop in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, types, row, plpgsql

The following code that I use returns an integer `1`:

```
CREATE TYPE my_test AS (
   foo Integer
  );

CREATE FUNCTION foo_out() 
  RETURNS SETOF Integer AS
$$ 
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
SELECT 1 as foo;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE FUNCTION foo1()
  RETURNS SETOF my_test
AS $$
DECLARE
    x my_test;
BEGIN
    FOR x IN    
        SELECT foo_out()
    LOOP     
        RETURN NEXT x;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

select * from foo1();
```

But why does the same code return:

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: (1)
> ```

if I change the return type to:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo_out() 
  RETURNS SETOF my_test
```

Which also should be an `integer`!? It could be the case that the system differs between the type integer and a custom type that includes an integer. What should be changed that the use of custom types is possible here?

Comment: You can use `select * from foo_out()` in second function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my_test` is a composite type, a row type, that *contains* a single integer field. It's *not* an `integer`.

When assigning to a record or row type in a [`FOR` loop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) all output columns from the query ***form*** the row. Your `SELECT` needs to return a single, unnested `integer` column, which is then nested into a row type matching your custom type `my_test`.
You can also assign to a list of scalar variables in a `FOR` loop, in which case columns from the query are assigned left to right to variables *as is* - not forming a row.

If the column itself ***is*** a row type, you have one level of nesting to many. The text representation of a row containing an integer field is '(1)' (with parentheses!), and that's what you see in the error message.

You can fix that by [extracting the integer field from the row with attribute notation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#FIELD-SELECTION):

```
SELECT (foo_out()).*
```

Or (more efficiently for multiple columns) by decomposing with:

```
SELECT * FROM foo_out()
```

#### Example Code

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo_out() 
  RETURNS SETOF my_test
  LANGUAGE sql AS
'SELECT ''(1)''::my_test';

CREATE FUNCTION foo1()
  RETURNS SETOF my_test
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   x my_test;
BEGIN
   FOR x IN    
      SELECT * FROM foo_out()
   LOOP     
      RETURN NEXT x;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e5c5e2edfbfdc325036e735a05ddea88)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/34ae6b/1)</sub>

Don't quote the language name `plpgsql`. It's an identifier.

Remember that looping is rarely needed, since most problems are more efficiently solved with a set-based approach (SQL only).

Related answers by Craig and Pavel:

- [Passing array of a composite type to stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914227/passing-array-of-a-composite-type-to-stored-procedure)