# Invalid input syntax for type integer: "(2,2)" with composite data type while executing function

Tags: postgresql, variable-assignment, plpgsql, rowtype

```
begin;
create type public.ltree as (a int, b int);
create  table public.parent_tree(parent_id int,l_tree ltree);
insert into public.parent_tree values(1,(2,2)),(2,(1,2)),(3, (1,28));
commit;
```

Trying to replicate the solution in this answer:

- [Format specifier for integer variables in format() for EXECUTE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656716/format-specifier-for-integer-variable)

For a function with composite type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_parent_ltree
            (_parent_id int, tbl_name regclass , OUT _l_tree ltree)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('SELECT l_tree FROM %s WHERE parent_id = $1', tbl_name)
   INTO  _l_tree
   USING _parent_id;
END
$func$;
```

The effective query executed:

```
select l_tree from parent_tree where parent_id = 1;
```

Executing the function:

```
select get_parent_ltree(1,'parent_tree');
select get_parent_ltree(1,'public.parent_tree');
```

I get this **error**:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "(2,2)"  
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function get_parent_ltree(integer,regclass) line 3 at EXECUTE
```

Context of line 3:

[image: line3 pic]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output parameter `_l_tree` is a "row variable". (A composite type is treated as row variable.) `SELECT INTO` assigns fields of a row variable one-by-one. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

> The optional ***`target`*** is a record variable, a row variable, or a comma-separated list of simple variables and record/row fields, [...]

So, currently (pg 14), a row or record variables must stand alone as *`target`*. Or as the according Postgres error message would put it:

> ```
> ERROR:  record variable cannot be part of multiple-item INTO list
> ```

This works:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_parent_ltree (IN  _parent_id int
                                                  , IN  _tbl_name  regclass
                                                  , OUT _l_tree    ltree)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('SELECT (l_tree).* FROM %s WHERE parent_id = $1', _tbl_name)
   INTO  _l_tree
   USING _parent_id;
END
$func$;
```

Or this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_parent_ltree2 (IN  _parent_id int
                                                   , IN  _tbl_name  regclass
                                                   , OUT _l_tree    ltree)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('SELECT (l_tree).a, (l_tree).b FROM %s WHERE parent_id = $1', _tbl_name)
   INTO  _l_tree.a, _l_tree.b
   USING _parent_id;
END
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=153f23b1cb4ea43de6f2af3613b5f724)*

I agree that this is rather tricky. One might expect that a composite field is treated as a single field (like a simple type). But that's currently not so in PL/pgSQL assignments.

A related quote from [the manual about composite types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html):

> A *composite type* represents the structure of a row or record; it is
> essentially just a list of field names and their data types.
> **PostgreSQL allows composite types to be used in many of the same ways that simple types can be used**.

Bold emphasis mine.
*Many*. Not *all*.

Related:

- [Use of custom return types in a FOR loop in plpgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900702/use-of-custom-return-types-in-a-for-loop-in-plpgsql/27918462#27918462)
- [PostgreSQL: ERROR: 42601: a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605174/postgresql-error-42601-a-column-definition-list-is-required-for-functions-ret/8611675#8611675)

---

Aside: Consider the [additional module `ltree`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html) instead of "growing your own". And if you continue working with your own composite type, consider a different name to avoid confusion / conflict with that module.

Comment: I know why I stay away from row types ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I don't disagree. I can handle them after a path of trial and tribulation. But I'd rather stick to simple types whenever possible. And that's my advice for beginners in any case.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I had no idea about this anomaly and feel ambivalent about it. I'm glad this behavior is documented, still I can't help but get the feeling that it's a masked shortcoming. And the error message a user receives in such a case is strange (to put it mildly).

Comment: @klin: Yeah, this is a dark back alley in PL/pgSQL town. What adds to the confusion is that a set-returning function with `RETURN QUERY` takes kind of the opposite approach: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=20ca42d96396a469b3c730b29486da3f)* There are reasons for everything, but the result is pretty confusing.

Comment: Or even: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=eeb184bfcc2f932bfee156c76de4cace)*

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a Postgres bug but Erwin clarifies the issue in the adjacent answer. One of the natural workarounds is to use an auxiliary text variable in the way like this:

```sql
create or replace function get_parent_ltree(_parent_id int, tbl_name regclass)
returns ltree language plpgsql as
$func$
declare
    rslt text;
begin
    execute format('select l_tree from %s where parent_id = $1', tbl_name)
    into rslt
    using _parent_id;
    return rslt::ltree;
end
$func$;
```

Comment: It seems to be related to PL/pgSQL. A `return query select ...` without dynamic SQL results in the same error. A `language sql` function (obviously without dynamic SQL) works however.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I think my answer can explain it.