# Malformed array literal when selecting into custom type within a postgresql function

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, plpgsql, literals

I have a postgresql custom type, containing arrays

```
CREATE TYPE route_part (
  nodea bigint[],
  edgea bigint[],
  geom geometry
);
```

And a function, returning this type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION net.get_route_part_dist(int8, int8, int4)
RETURNS route_part
AS
$BODY$
DECLARE routerec route_part;
BEGIN
SELECT INTO routerec
  ...
;

RETURN routerec;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

This function works as expected and returns `route_part` composite type.
I'm trying to use it inside another "wrapper" function, that looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION net.get_route(beg_ int8, end_ int8, mida int8[], dist int4)
RETURNS route_part
AS
$BODY$
DECLARE routerec route_part;
BEGIN
SELECT INTO routerec net.get_route_part_dist(beg_, end_, dist);
RETURN routerec;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

I get an error on the select query.

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "(
{303513543,2289605239,...,306687989}","
{2585314,264212,...,1088633}",
0102000020110F000029000000AE47E11A81754F41C3F5280C07F25C)"
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

I don't cast types to strings or other types, so I can't figure out why the returned value considered to have a malformed array.
Any clues?

Comment: When using a construction like this `SELECT INTO routerec
  (net.get_route_part_dist(beg_, end_, dist)).nodea,
  (net.get_route_part_dist(beg_, end_, dist)).edgea,
  (net.get_route_part_dist(beg_, end_, dist)).geom;` it works, but adds an overhead of calling a function three times instead of one. I'm sure there is a way of returning the fetched type without reconstructing it from parts.

Comment: You forgot to provide your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to assign decomposed values:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION net.get_route(beg_ int8, end_ int8, mida int8[], dist int4)
  RETURNS route_part AS
$func$
DECLARE
   routerec route_part;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO routerec * FROM net.get_route_part_dist(beg_, end_, dist);
   RETURN routerec;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Since `routerec` is a row type (composite type), The columns of the `SELECT` list must match the columns of the row type. The form you had would attempt to fit the value (as a whole) returned by `net.get_route_part_dist()` into the ***first column*** of `routerec`.

[Quoting the manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)

> If a row or a variable list is used as target, the query's result
>   columns must exactly match the structure of the target as to number
>   and data types

Postgres tries to fit your composite type (or rather its text representation) into `bigint[]`, the first column of the composite type `routerec`. The error message you quoted is the consequence.

[Explanation in the manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT)

> If the expression's result data type doesn't match the variable's data
>   type, the value will be coerced as though by an assignment cast (see
>   [Section 10.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/typeconv-query.html)). If no assignment cast is known for the pair of data
>   types involved, the PL/pgSQL interpreter will attempt to convert the
>   result value textually, that is by applying the result type's output
>   function followed by the variable type's input function. Note that
>   this could result in run-time errors generated by the input function,
>   if the string form of the result value is not acceptable to the input function.

This can be confusing and fooled the first time as well. The distinction seems necessary since `INTO` allows assigning a ***list of target variables*** at once.
The bottom line is this: Decompose row types with `SELECT * FROM ...` when assigning to a row / record / composite type with `INTO`. Else it will be assigned to the first target column as a whole.

***Avoid*** these inefficient forms:
Like you commented:

<strike>`SELECT INTO routerec (net.get_route_part_dist(beg_, end_, dist)).nodea
                    , (net.get_route_part_dist(beg_, end_, dist)).edgea
                    , (net.get_route_part_dist(beg_, end_, dist)).geom;`</strike>

Or, less verbose, but equally inefficient:

<strike>`SELECT INTO routerec (net.get_route_part_dist(beg_, end_, dist)).*;`</strike>

Each would evaluate the function multiple times - as opposed to:
`SELECT INTO routerec * FROM net.get_route_part_dist(beg_, end_, dist)`

Related:

- [Use of custom return types in a FOR loop in plpgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900702/use-of-custom-return-types-in-a-for-loop-in-plpgsql/27918462#27918462)
- [Passing array of a composite type to stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914227/passing-array-of-a-composite-type-to-stored-procedure)

### Simple alternative

The simple alternative for your simple case: direct assignment (without `INTO`):

```
  routerec := net.get_route_part_dist(beg_, end_, dist);
  RETURN routerec;
```

Simple assignment only allows a *single* target to begin with.
Or return the result directly:

```
  RETURN net.get_route_part_dist(beg_, end_, dist);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! You cleared my sky on this. My wrapper is a bit more complex to just return directly, but `SELECT * FROM` should work for me. I just didn't realize it tried to fit the result into the firs column of my complex type.